# Disabling JIT compiler on command line (CLI)

Tags: nginx, hhvm

I´m just evaluating HHVM + NGINX instead of PHP7 + APACHE2 for one of my projects. This project serves a Webfrontend via NGINX and has also some PHP jobs **running as service in the background**.

My issue now is, that HHVM + JIT compilation isn´t a good idea for command line processes as I read (bytecode has to be created for each call).

So my question is: **How can I disable JIT compilation only for CLI calls to HHVM?** Is there a parameter I can pass to the call similar to "-v Eval.JitWarmupRequests=0"?

Thanks in advance for an hint,
Michael

Comment: "My issue now is, that HHVM + JIT compilation isn´t a good idea for command line processes as I read (bytecode has to be created for each call)." The full story here is extremely complicated; you should benchmark what you're doing to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the [INI settings page](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/configuration/INI-settings#jit-settings) (under JIT), there's the `hhvm.jit` INI setting that can be used to disable the JIT.

To pass this along on the command line, you use the `-d` flag. So, you'd want `hhvm -d hhvm.jit=0`

Comment: Yup, that's the HDF version. HDF is being phased out in favour of the INI version, so `-v` will eventually go away.